# How to test static method invokation in Android?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I have an Android activity and I want to write a unit test, which verifies that in `onResume` the activity checks whether the Internet is available.

```
public class MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setContentView(R.layout.connect_to_server);

        // Internet availability check

        final IInternetAvailabilityChecker checker =  InternetAvailabilityChecker.create(this);

        if (!checker.isInternetAvailable())
        {
            Utils.showMessageBox(this, R.string.app_name,
                    R.string.internet_not_available);
            return;
        }
```

In the test, I want to verify that `MyActiviy.onResume` calls the `InternetAvailabilityChecker.create` method.

How can I do it (with any free mocking framework compatible with Android) ?

I tried to use PowerMock for this (see example below), but when I try to run the test, I get errors like *MockTest.java:7: package org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations does not exist*.

Maven:

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>1.5.1</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Unit test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { InternetAvailabilityChecker.class })
public class MyActivityPowerMockTest {
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void test()
    {
        final IInternetAvailabilityChecker checker = mock(IInternetAvailabilityChecker.class);

        when(checker.isInternetAvailable()).thenReturn(false);

        mockStatic(InternetAvailabilityChecker.class);
        expect(InternetAvailabilityChecker.create(any(Activity.class))).andReturn(checker);
        replay(InternetAvailabilityChecker.class);

        final MyActivity objectUnderTest = new MyActivity();

        objectUnderTest.onResume();

        // Verify that the method InternetAvailabilityChecker.create was called
        verify(InternetAvailabilityChecker.class); 

        // TODO: Verify that Utils.showMessageBox has been invoked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing a Maven dependency.  According to [this query](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest/jar) the annotations are supplied by:

- org.powermock / powermock-core
- org.powermock / powermock-easymock-single-jar-release-full
- org.powermock / powermock-mockito-single-jar-release-full